# CMake include_directories does not help to find header files

Tags: c++, cmake

The directory structure of the project is:

```
project
| bar
| | src
| | | src.cpp (include "a.hpp")
| | | CMakeLists.txt (3)
| | third_party
| | | a.hpp
| | CMakeLists.txt (2)
| main.cpp (include "bar/src/src.cpp")
| CMakeLists.txt (1)
```

CMakeLists1.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
set(TARGET Foo)
project(${TARGET})
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -O3" )
add_subdirectory(bar)
add_executable(${TARGET}_out  main.cpp)
```

CMakeLists2.txt:

```
include_directories(.)
include_directories(third_party)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

CMakeLists3.txt:

```
add_library(${TARGET} SHARED src.cpp)
```

However, the project won't compile because `src.cpp` cannot find `a.hpp`. I used

```
get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
  message(STATUS "dir3='${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

to check the included directories from the `src` folder which showed that `third_party` was included, then why can't src.cpp find the header which was already in the included path?

If I move `include_directories(third_party)` from `CMakeLists2` to `CMakeLists1` (change to `bar/third_party`), the code compiles like magic, why??

Comment: It's better to paste the full CMake output message here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'include_directories' affects the include directories of targets in that CMakeLists.txt, and its descendants.  I think the issue is that the executable is added (targeted) in CMakeLists.txt 1; src.cpp isn't actually in CMakeLists 2's target/build scope, so it isn't affected by 'include_directories' calls in CMakeLists 2.

Comment: I assume add_subdirectory extends scope, so 2 is 1's descendant and 3 is 2's, right? And it is strange if I remove the add_exe in 1, i.e. simply build the library, src.cpp now can find a.h, why?

Comment: The executable is targeted in CMakeLists 1 (a parent of 2), and the library is targeted in CMakeLists 3 (a descendent of 2).  Therefore, the library is compiled with the include_directories defined in 2, while the exectable is not.   If the executable included the library, rather than the file src.cpp, then they would both compile.